# Center link text over image

Tags: html, css

I have an asp.net page that I'm trying to have an image be in the center of a table cell and have that image be a link to another page.  I'm not too good with CSS but I tried a couple of different things and here's a screenshot of my outcome:
[image]

As you can see, the link is beside the image...I'd like to have that link be in the center of that image, but also have the image be clickable (as part of the link), like so:
[image]

Here's my table (keep in mind that this is part of a ASPx GridView control so it gets repeated for each row in it's datasource):

```
<table style="text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><strong>Request ID</strong></td>
    <td class="field">Date</td>
    <td class="field">Requestor</td>
    <td class="field">Status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="4" align="center" style="position:relative;">
        <a href='<%#"pending_requests.aspx?RID=" + Eval("RequestID") %>'><img src="../images/document.png" alt=""  style="z-index: -1"><%# Eval("RequestID") %></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="labelRequestDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RequestDate") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
    </td>
    <td>
        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="labelICAO" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ICAO") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
    </td>
    <td>
        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="labelStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="field" colspan="4">Summary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" valign="top">
        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="labelSummary" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <strong>Description:</strong>
        <br />
        <%# Eval("Description") %>
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>Comments</strong>
        <br />
        <%# Eval("Comments") %>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The class "field" simply makes the text bold and sets the width to 10%.

Please keep in mind that I need this to work in IE7 and above, Chrome, and Firefox as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the ASP, including the CSS.

Comment: Or put it in a fiddle

Comment: Sorry I didn't do that in the first place but ASPx rendered to html is HUGE and because I'm using a built-in control (GridView), it creates all sorts of styles and such that it makes it close to impossible to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a background image for a `div` tag which is wrapped around using an `a` tag?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3PCR/) (You can remove border, just used it for test purpose)

```
<a href="#"><div><span>495</span></div></a>

div {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNy9C.jpg');
    height: 90px;
    width: 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: relative;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    top:35%;
    left: 20%;
}

a {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Allen...this worked great with a few tweaks (some existing css was messing it up as well).